# pygame mouse registering multiple clicks

Tags: list, function, pygame, mouse

I have two lists and a function. The function appends items from one list to the other every time the mouse is clicked. However, the mouse sometimes appends more than one item from the list. After doing a little digging around I found that this was because the mouse is held down for too long. How do I make it so regardless of how long the mouse is held down, it only appends one item? Here is a code sample:

```
list_A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list_B = []

def appender():
    if mouse.get_pressed()[0] = 1
        list_B.append(list_A[len(list_A)-1])
        list_A.remove(list_A[len(list_A)-1])
```

I call the appended function inside of a game loop with all the right setups. However, it appends multiple items when the mouse is held down, any suggestions?

Comment: instead using mouse.get_pressed can you try using
     `for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
            #do something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest an alternative way to detect mouse click. loop through `events` in pygame and see if any of them are `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`:

```
list_A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list_B = []
def appender():
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            list_B.append(list_A[len(list_A)-1])
            list_A.remove(list_A[len(list_A)-1])
```